# Cassandra : LOCAL_QUORUM vs QUORUM, when all datacenter/servers are physically locals, on the same 10gbps network

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise

I have two Cassandra datacenter, but all the servers are in the same building, connected with `10 gbps` network.

I don't plan to have servers in another location.

The RF is 2 in each datacenter.

I need to ensure strong consistency, so I plan to use QUORUM.

**Question :** are there any advantages for me of using LOCAL_QUORUM instead of QUORUM ?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Are there any advantages for me of using LOCAL_QUORUM instead of QUORUM?

The most important consideration here, is that with 2 DCs with RF == 2, `QUORUM` and `LOCAL_QUORUM` equate to different values (number of replicas to be contacted).

- `LOCAL_QUORUM` == 2
- `QUORUM` == 3

So the *advantage* I see with `LOCAL_QUORUM`, would be that the application would be waiting on fewer replicas.  With 2 DCs and 2 replicas in each DC, operations @ `LOCAL_QUORUM` would wait for responses from 2 replicas.

`QUORUM` operations would consider all 4 replicas across the cluster, and wait for a response from 3.  So there would likely be a slight performance advantage to `LOCAL_QUORUM` (awaiting fewer replicas to respond).

The downside, is that using `LOCAL_QUORUM` in this case wouldn't be able to tolerate a node being down.  So if a single node crashed or became unresponsive, then all operations will fail until that node is resurrected.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Aaron, you'd have no fault tolerance with local_quorum in this configuration, so I think it's worth considering to add a new node to each of these DCs.

By doing that, you'd maintain local_quorum of 2 (against a new quorum of 4) but become fault tolerant and survive if a node goes down on each side.